# Codeigniter HMVC does not load config file

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I am trying to load a file from `config/common` folder which does not load.

I downloaded codeigniter framework and HMVC framework from [here](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads/) and copied to third_party and core folder as per its description and created a config file under `application->config->common->test_config.php` like below

```
application
    config
       common
          test_config.php
```

i have controller (`MY_Controller`) under core folder and i want to load this file like `$this->load->config(common/test);`
But it does not load `test_config.php`. Can someone give some clue to load this file.

Regards

Rabinarayan

Comment: Just download this version and start using it https://github.com/jlamim/ci3-hmvc

Answer (score 1):

You're using wrong/missing file. Download [**Codeigniter HMVC from here**](https://github.com/alzen8work/CodeIgniter-HMVC) and [**Config file placed here**](https://github.com/alzen8work/CodeIgniter-HMVC/blob/master/application/config/config.php)

---

Structure will be

```
application
    config
        config.php
```

---

**Note:** Use PHP 5.6 or higher

Comment: its true that i need to put my config.php file in config folder for use in global but i am using a custom config file and i want to use it where i want to. So is it possible to place them different folder in config folder

Comment: if you add anything to this file, It can access through all over the project. And Question is why you need *custom config file* ??

Comment: i have different modules and i have few common configuration that i want to share between modules(not global configuration)

Comment: set it in array elements so when you call it it will load respective settings only

Comment: it did not helped i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that with CI-HMVC, the `$this->config->load()` method is looking for config files only inside folders called "config" in any paths loaded.

so if you really need subfolder, you have to create a 'config' folder within your 'subfolder' ... I'd advise you not to put them in the config folder of the application, but in the third_party folder

*(note that this would probably work if you put this in the `config` folder but it seems a bit redundant to me to have `config/subfolder/config/config_file` - plus I'm sure this is not very orthodox )*

```
third_party/
     subfolder/
          config/
             custom_config.php
```

then load the config/subfolder into CI as a path

`$this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'third_party/subfolder');`

and finally load your custom config file :

`$this->config->load('custom_config');`